# Scroll one div to trigger another div to scroll at a different speed with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I have two scrollable divs, div A and div B.

I'd like that when I scroll div A, div B also scrolls in the same direction but more slowly.
I'd also like to be able to scroll div B independently while hovering over it.

I've worked out a solution in jquery, as shown in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j4nuxq97/11/

```js
var position = $(window).scrollTop();

$(".div-a").scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(".div-a").scrollTop();
  if (scroll > position) {
    var y = $(".div-b").scrollTop();
    $(".div-b").scrollTop(y + 20);
  } else {
    var y = $(".div-b").scrollTop();
    $(".div-b").scrollTop(y - 20);
  }
  position = scroll;
});
```

```css
div{
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:30px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-a">
1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>21<br>22<br>23<br>24<br>25<br>26<br>27<br>28<br>29<br>30<br>
</div>

<div class="div-b">
1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>21<br>22<br>23<br>24<br>25<br>26<br>27<br>28<br>29<br>30<br>
</div>
```

the problem is that it's a really unpleasant animation:

- div B always moves after div A has, rather than at the same time
- the animation is really jerky, and the amount moved varies based on the speed at which div A is scrolled

Can anyone recommend the best way to make this feel smoother, and closer to the way the animation on this site feels: http://spassky-fischer.fr/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this it's working for me.

JsFiddle link [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/k9hz7x0w/)

```html
<style>
div{
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:30px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-a" id="col" onscroll="OnScroll(this)">
1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>21<br>22<br>23<br>24<br>25<br>26<br>27<br>28<br>29<br>30<br>
</div>

<div class="div-b" id="col1">
1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>21<br>22<br>23<br>24<br>25<br>26<br>27<br>28<br>29<br>30<br>
</div>

<script>
function OnScroll(div) 
{
 var div1 = document.getElementById("col1");
 div1.scrollTop = div.scrollTop;
}   
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answering but this doesn't do any of the things i specified. it doesn't scroll more slowly than the first div, and it doesn't scroll at the same time - if you've got any further suggestions i'd be keen to hear them!